# How to get all NOT NULL values of database using findall()

Tags: yii2

My intention is to get all values of database, which are NOT NULL. I try like this, but I dont succeed with it. I will get all values of database instead of NOT NULL values.

```
public function FindAllGeoData($fkBez) {
    $ArrayOfFk = array();
    $fk = EKontakt::find()->where($fkBez != NULL, [$fkBez => NULL])->asArray()->all();
    var_dump($fk);
    die();
}
```

How to code `$fk` correctly?

Comment: What is the value of `$fkBez`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the examples in the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#where)

```
$fk = EKontakt::find()->where(['not', [$fkBez => NULL]])->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: Great job. Thx for this solution. Gave reputation points for U!